# Closure of regular languages to $A(L)=\{zyx|x,y,z \in \{0,1\}^*, xyz \in L\}$

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language, context-free-grammar, regular-expressions

Given: $A(L)=\{zyx|x,y,z \in \{0,1\}^*, xyz \in L\}$

> Given $L \subseteq\{0,1\}^*$, Prove/Disprove:
>
> - If $L$ is regular $\implies$ $A(L)$ is regular
> - If $L$ is context free$\implies$ $A(L)$ is context free

I'd like a proof not using a construction of DFA/NFA.

Comment: If you do not want automata (and neither grammars I suppose), in which form would you like your language to be given? Just by using common closure properties you will probably not be able to prove something that depends on the structure of the single words.